# Display IPython variables without entering using whos

Tags: python, ipython, workspace

Is there a way to view a list of the IPython variables currently in the workspace without having to send the command 'whos'.  I often find myself not remembering what variable names I want to use while typing a command.

In IPython, I have to erase the current line I was typing and send a 'whos' statement to see which variables are currently available.  Normally, in GUI based tools like MATLAB I would just look to the right at my Workspace Variable window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others said, you can have as many frontends as you like on the same Ipython kernel, i.e 2 command windows for one kernel for example. If you are using the Qt console, shortcuts can get you close to what you want.

Start a second tab with the same kernel with **Ctrl+Shift+T**.
Then you just write your code on the first tab, and, when you need the output of `whos`, press **Ctrl+PageDown** to get to the other tab, and you can run `whos` without deleting your code in the first tab.

Comment: This resolved my issue very nicely and opened me to a very cool feature if ipython, thanks.

Command: ipython qtconsole

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a direct answer, but may be useful to you anyway.  At least on the system I'm on,

Ctrl-a will position the cursor at the beginning of the line

Ctrl-k will 'kill' the line (think cut)

type whos

Ctrl-y will 'yank' the line as it was back (think paste)

These are emacs keybindings, BTW, and show in many places like Bash and anywhere that uses the readline library.

Answer (score 4):

You can have as many IPython frontends as you like on a single IPy kernel, so yes, if you wanted another front end you could do that, but it seems heavy-handed. Can you not use IPython Notebook?

Comment: To elucidate, the notebook has multiple cells, so rather than switching to another frontend, you could jump to a new cell to run `whos`, then return to the cell where you were entering your command.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Yes, that was precisely what I was getting at. In fairness, if this is a common issue, it's probably best to think a bit more creatively about your variable names too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if you can access the variables of IPython from another instance of the shell?

Because the way it is now, you have a *single* command window where you interact with the shell by issuing commands, so unlike MATLAB there is no other window to view additional information, so I don't see how this would be possible unless you have another instance of IPython somehow accessing the information from your current shell.

So the answer would seemingly be *no*.

(If it is somehow possible to do this, I'll be just as happy as you to find out though)

Comment: I bet it'd be possible to write something that would connect to the IPython kernel and occasionally poll `whos` in another window....

Comment: Well any way to access the current workspace variables without forcing me to erase my current typed-in command.

Comment: @ChristopherDorian Unless you use a different front-end or make some changes as mentioned elsewhere on the age, I don't see a way. Those must be some long (long) commands :-) .. in the past I've made use of tab-completions which worked well as long as I remembered the start of the variables, I guess that's not a viable option for you given the question (and of course doesn't list all of the variables, only the ones that match the start of what you provided and what the system has)

Answer (score 1):

In iPython notebook, call the magic function, "%qtconsole", and a console will appear with the same kernel.  Alternatively, in the Terminal, you can type, "ipython qtconsole --existing" to launch the most recent kernel in the qtconsole.  If you know the name of the kernel (as shown in the terminal output when launched), then you can explicitly tell it like so, "ipython qtconsole --existing 87f7d2c0"