# Jupyter Notebook: Equivalent to Matlab's Workspace?

Tags: matlab, jupyter-notebook

Is there any Matlab workspace equivalent in Jupyter Notebook that I can directly check for the variables that I'm using? And I can easily copy them out for some other use?

In matlab, the workspace look like this:

[image]

Or, if there is none, is there any related resources that I can read, so I can make one on my own?

---

The question is not duplicated, this is some progress I find so far

A variable explorer:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1516

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display IPython variables without entering using whos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991368/display-ipython-variables-without-entering-using-whos)

Comment: @Dev-iL, I'm sorry, I didn't get it. Could you give a little bit info about how to do this based on the link you provide?

Comment: @cqcn1991 The main idea is to open another notebook running the same kernel. Then you can perform whos on that new tab while coding in the original tab. Since they are using the same kernel they will share the variables

Answer (score 3):

For JupyterLab I can recommend the JupyterLab [VariableInspector extension](https://github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector). It is very similar to matlab and allows to inspect values inside arrays.

[image]

Note that you need to have both `numpy` and `pandas` installed for the array value inspection to work.

You should be very careful though when using this extension. Jupyter will become unresponsive if you have to much data in your variables. See for example https://github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector/issues/122.

Comment: You should be very careful though when using this extension. Jupyter will become unresponsive if you have to much data in your variables. See for example https://github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector/issues/122

Answer (score 1):

You can use  the Jupyter contrib extension  [Variable Inspector](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/varInspector):

[image]